# Get a sequence between two column difference?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am developing a chequebook management system. I want to create a cheque series  which is to be the difference between two columns. Unused  cheques can be shown on  payment module I want to show all free and unused cheque

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some sample data to illustrate what you mean by "series which is to be the difference between two columns"

Comment: Its preferred to add data as text not as an image.

Comment: And the image still doesn't show where these numbers are supposed to come from?

Comment: The numbers  it  to be inserted by the end user to create a chequebook

Comment: Sorry your question doesn't make sense as written.

Comment: I want to generate a series that is to be difference between  chequebookto  and chequebook from column Like difference  in its first  is 150-100  =50 series should be 101 ,102,103 upto 150

Comment: As I asked before, please provide some data which illustrates that.

Answer (score 0):

based on your brief description, I guess you wanted a listing of unused `chequeno`

You can use recursive cte to generate the list of available cheque no based on the `chequebookfrom` and `chequebookto` and then check with the `payments` table for those used `chequeno`

```
; with rcte as
(
    select bankid, chequeno = chequebookfrom, chequebookto
    from   chequebook

    union all

    select bankid, chequeno = chequeno + 1, chequebookto
    from   rcte
    where  chequeno  < chequebookto
)
select *
from   rcte r
where  not exists
       (
            select *
            from   payments x
            where  x.bankid = r.bankid
            and    x.chequeno = r.chequeno
       )
```